# How to solve this problem while using tab bar from ant-design in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I dont want to give up trying to learn react native, but i get so many errors during running android emulator.
It gets boring, I added the error pic for you to see (it says my question couldnt be submitted ...  )

This is the code:

```
import {Icon, SearchBar, TabBar} from '@ant-design/react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';


export default function Footer(props) {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState('redTab');

  const renderContent = pageText => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
        <SearchBar placeholder="Search" showCancelButton />
        <Text style={{ margin: 50 }}>{pageText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
  const onChangeTab = (tabName) => {
    setSelectedTab(tabName);
  }

  return (
    <TabBar
      unselectedTintColor="#949494"
      tintColor="#33A3F4"
      barTintColor="#f5f5f5"
    >
      <TabBar.Item
        title="Life"
        icon={<Icon name="home" />}
        selected={selectedTab === 'blueTab'}
        onPress={() => onChangeTab('blueTab')}
      >
        {renderContent('Life Tab')}
      </TabBar.Item>
      <TabBar.Item
        icon={<Icon name="ordered-list" />}
        title="Koubei"
        badge={2}
        selected={selectedTab === 'redTab'}
        onPress={() => onChangeTab('redTab')}
      >
        {renderContent('Koubei Tab')}
      </TabBar.Item>
      <TabBar.Item
        icon={<Icon name="like" />}
        title="Friend"
        selected={selectedTab === 'greenTab'}
        onPress={() => onChangeTab('greenTab')}
      >
        {renderContent('Friend Tab')}
      </TabBar.Item>
      <TabBar.Item
        icon={<Icon name="user" />}
        title="My"
        selected={selectedTab === 'yellowTab'}
        onPress={() => onChangeTab('yellowTab')}
      >""
        {renderContent('My Tab')}
      </TabBar.Item>
    </TabBar>
  );

}
```

how can i solve the problem, here is the error i get: [image]

new error here, after adding dependencies[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should install the peer dependencies, sadly the offical docs not give it. You can encounter them in the github readme only

```
npm install @react-native-community/cameraroll @react-native-picker/picker @react-native-community/segmented-control @react-native-community/slider react-native-pager-view
```

Remember to check all packages githubs readme and follow the instructions if them need more installations instructions.

Comment: Why do i have to install peer dependencies if i dont use them(cameraroll, picker, pager view) (idk what they even are tho) 
I installed them now, and i have another error... Im editing the question and adding the error if you could help me

Comment: I run this `npm add @react-native-community/async-storage`  and this `npm install @react-native-community/async-storage`but still same error

Comment: I don't know why u need them I suppose to use the components they offer... try to follow https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install

Comment: thanks for replying. i just decided not to use ant-design, because the error i get is because of ant-design ui library, when i delete the components of it, it works.. I just couldnt get ant-design run, so i will do without it